# ModelStateDictionary Cyclic Dependency Injection loop error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection

## EDIT

The particular part that I am confused about is the error.

5) Injection of dependency ModelStateDictionary into parameter dictionary of constructor of type ModelStateDictionary

ModelStateDictionary has a constructor that accepts a ModelStateDictionary object. Is this why / where the error is occurring? If so, how do I resolve it as ModelStateDictionary is not a n object that I can directly modify.

## Original

I've been trying to get dependency injection setup to work on for my controllers on in an asp.net mvc app. But I end up with a cyclic dependency on the System.Web.Mvc.ModelStateDictionary. I've done some searching ... [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7659379/dependency-injection-with-cyclic-dependency) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772840/dependency-injection-and-modelstatewrapper) and others and I've tried some of the suggestions like creating a property (maybe I just don't know where to place them) instead of passing it through the constructor. However it seems to me that ninject is having a problem with the System.Web.Mvc.ModelStateDictionary class or definition. I get the following error ...

```
Activation path:
5) Injection of dependency ModelStateDictionary into parameter dictionary of constructor of type ModelStateDictionary
4) Injection of dependency ModelStateDictionary into parameter modelState of constructor of type ModelStateWrapper
3) Injection of dependency IValidationDictionary into parameter validationDictionary of constructor of type ProjectService
2) Injection of dependency IProjectService into parameter prjService of constructor of type ProjectController
1) Request for ProjectController
```

My classes are pretty much defined as follows. I have obviously removed some of the extraneous stuff ...

```
public class ProjectController : Controller
{
    private IProjectService _prjService;
    private IMembershipService _membershipService;

    public ProjectController(IProjectService prjService,IMembershipService membershipService )
    {
        _membershipService = membershipService;
        _prjService = prjService;
    }

}


public class ProjectService : ServiceBase, IProjectService
{
    public ProjectService(IValidationDictionary validationDictionary) : base(validationDictionary) { }
}


public class ServiceBase
{
    private readonly IValidationDictionary _validationDictionary;

    public IValidationDictionary ValidationDictionary { get { return _validationDictionary; } }

    public ServiceBase(IValidationDictionary validationDictionary)
    {
        _validationDictionary = validationDictionary;
    }

}


public interface IProjectService
{
    // interface has other properties 

    IValidationDictionary ValidationDictionary { get; }
}

public class ModelStateWrapper : IValidationDictionary
{
    private ModelStateDictionary _modelState;

    public ModelStateWrapper(ModelStateDictionary modelState)
    {
        _modelState = modelState;
    }

    public ModelStateWrapper()
    {

    }

    public void AddError(string key, string errorMessage)
    {
        _modelState.AddModelError(key, errorMessage);
    }

    public bool IsValid
    {
        get { return _modelState.IsValid; }
    }
}
```

The definition of ModelStateDictionary is as follows ... at least as far as I think it pertains to this problem.

```
[Serializable]
public class ModelStateDictionary : IDictionary<string, ModelState>, ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, ModelState>>, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, ModelState>>, IEnumerable
{
    public ModelStateDictionary();

    public ModelStateDictionary(ModelStateDictionary dictionary);
}
```

The bindings I've set up for ninject are as follows ...

```
        kernel.Bind<IMembershipService>().To<AuthMembershipService>();
        kernel.Bind<IProjectService>().To<ProjectService>();
        kernel.Bind<IValidationDictionary>().To<ModelStateWrapper>();
```

Please let me know if I can provide any more information ... I initially tried to use structuremap but couldn't make the DI work ... I seem to have at least got ninject set up and working for the most part.

Thanks,

Comment: Show us the code of the `ModelStateWrapper`.

Comment: apologies Steven, I thought I had added it. I've added it now.

Answer (score 1):

Ninject chooses the constructor with the most parameters it knows how to create by default. In this case the second constructor is choosen. This would result in a stackoverflow since it would have to create a ModelStateWrapper to inject into the ModelStateWrapper and andother to inject into the second one, ......

Unless there is a really good reason for the second construcotr you should simply delete it. Otherwise you have to give here enough information that we can understand why there is this second constructor.

Comment: Remo, the ninject documentation says the following ... When asked to instantiate an object, Ninject will look at the type’s available public constructors and pick the one with the most parameters it knows how to resolve — **or the parameterless one if there aren’t any suitable ones.** So my expectation would've been that ninject couldn't create the object using the constructor with the most parameters so it should've fallen back to using the parameterless constructor. Right? What is it that I am missing?

Comment: ModelStateDictionary is implicitly bound to itsself. So Ninject knows how to resolve it.

Comment: Right ... it should be shouldn't it ... but they why does it fail on that step ... 5) Injection of dependency ModelStateDictionary into parameter dictionary of constructor of type ModelStateDictionary ... Also what second constructor? The modelStateWrapper constructor accepts a ModelStateDictionary not a ModelStateWrapper ...

Comment: ModelStateWrapper has no problem. It is the ModelStateDictionary which wants another ModelStateDictionary which wants another ModelStateDictionary which ....... => stackoverflow

Comment: right so how do I solve this problem? How do I ensure that ninject chooses the right constructor for this System.Web.Mvc class?

Comment: I don't think you want to create one at all. What you want is to reuse Controller.ModelState. The only way you can to it is to pass it to your service at initialization. In my opinion you shouldn't delegate the error handling to the service. but rather map some error information returned by the service to the model state in the controller. Otherwise you will tightly couple the view and the service.

Comment: hrrmmm ... thanks Remo, I'll have to think about that when I get home, but that sounds like good advice :)